# Launch widget from code

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way we can launch the widget from our application immediately without user have to choose the widget.
So it like automatically add widget to our home screen using code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done, if you are willing to modify the Launcher code. But modifying it is not recommended for your purpose as it tightly couples with your app.

Answer (score 5):

No, this cannot be done.